# Perl script to store device serial number and install apk using adb

Tags: android, perl, adb

What I want to do is to capture the device serial numbers and store them in an array or list. Then I want to install my apk on various android devices that I connect to my system.I am trying to make a perl script that can do this for me.

Something like this:

```
if($ostype eq 'MSWin32') {

  system("title Android");

    $adbcommand_devices = "adb devices";

    $adbcommand_install = "adb -s xxxxxxxx install HelloWorld.apk";
}

  if(`adb -s xxxxxxxx get-state` =~ m/device/i) {
          system($adbcommand_devices);            
          system($adbcommand_install);

         }
 else {
    print "Device is offline\n";
}
```

The serial number should come from the currently connected device.

Comment: If [IPC::Run3](http://p3rl.org/IPC::Run3) (or IPC::Run) works on Windows, that'll make your life much easier. I suspect it does from the docs. You can easily capture the output from 'adb devices' with it.

Comment: Can you please provide a example code on how to approach this.thanks

Comment: OK, I've added an example (as an answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of just the `adb devices` command using [`IPC::Run3`](http://p3rl.org/IPC%3a%3aRun3):

```
use strict;
use warnings qw(all);

use IPC::Run3;
use Carp qw(croak confess cluck);
use Data::Dumper;

my $ADB_PATH = '/path/to/adb';  # EDIT THIS

my @devices = get_devices();
print Dumper(\@devices);
exit 0;

# subs
sub get_devices {
    my $adb_out;
    run3 [$ADB_PATH, 'devices'], undef, \$adb_out, undef;
    $? and cluck "Warning: non-zero exit status from adb ($?)";

    my @res = $adb_out =~ m/^([[:xdigit:]]+) \s+ device$/xmg;
    return wantarray ? @res : \@res;
}
```

For a lot of this, you may be able to use [`qx`/``` `` ```](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) as well. E.g., you could replace the `run3` with `` my $adb_out = `$ADB_PATH devices`; `` (because you didn't need to pass anything in to it, just out, and also didn't need to avoid the shell.)

Comment: Thanks, I currently have PERL ver 5.6.1 and for IPC::Run3 I need 5.8 minimum, I will upgrade and try this.

Comment: @Noble6: I [don't see](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RJBS/IPC-Run3-0.045/Makefile.PL) any 5.8 dependency for IPC::Run3, but if there is, you could download an older version [from its CPAN page](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/IPC-Run3-0.045/). But yeah, 5.6.1 is almost 11 years old, you really ought to upgrade!

Comment: With 5.6, I run into following error  
Installing package 'IPC-Run3'...
Downloading http://ppm.activestate.com/PPMPackages/5.6/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread/IPC-Run3-0.030.tar.gz ...                                                                 
Error installing package 'IPC-Run3': Error reading                  http://ppm.activestate.com/PPMPackages/5.6/MSWin32-x86-multi-thread/IPC-Run3-0.030.tar.gz                                               If I unzip the package and then try to install it, It shows a dependency on Test::More. I can't find Test:More on the web.

Comment: @Noble6: Ah, not sure about ActiveState's PPMs. Upgrading is probably in order (possibly to Strawberry Perl, so you can use normal CPAN tools)