# Retrieve Device ID from android using perl

Tags: android, perl, automation

I have 3-4 android devices connected to my laptop (with working ADB on windows). Now I want to trigger Youtube app on all these devices simultaneously and run that for a certain duration at a given time. The script will read the devices connected and trigger the app on it's own.

Requirement:
Is there a way I can take out the **Unique Device ID** and store it somewhere and use it for my rest of the programming?

**For example:** 
C:\Users\Arka.B>adb devices
List of devices attached

94e38259        device

94e38260        device 2

94e38261        device 3

94e38262        device 4

**Questions:**

- How do I take out this unique device id (94e38259, 94e38260, etc in this case) from each of these devices and trigger some other actions like launching an app or installing an APK?

Comment: What part of your code is not working? you need to show all your code

Comment: This is the only code I have. rest part is my requirement.

Comment: ok but people here will always be willing to trouble shoot and help with issues in your code, but stack is not a sight where you write a requirement and people write code for you

Comment: At least if one can tell me how to get the unique id of the android device using perl. That would solve my problem, I am editing the question.

Comment: try here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843393/perl-script-to-store-device-serial-number-and-install-apk-using-adb

Comment: yeah already read that when I was building up the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the device ids using following script:

```
my $output = `adb devices`;
my @devices = split("\n", $output);
my @deviceids;
foreach(@devices){
    chomp($_);
    push(@deviceids, $1) if($_ =~ /(.+)\s+device$/);
}
```